# How to delete extra characters in gvim "shell command mode"

Tags: vim

I am trying to switch to "shell mode" in `gvim` and execute shell commands by `:!bash` live in vim but when I do a `backspace` I get weird characters and the whole line just spoils and I have to repeat the process again. This also occurs when I try to press the arrow keys. How can I remove this annoying behaviour?

Check the blow screenshot, I hope it helps to understand my question

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The "shell" used to execute external commands via `:!` in GVim is a "dumb shell" with very  little in terms of capabilities.

If you *absolutely* want to run an interactive shell session from within Vim, you should do it via `:help :terminal`, which gives you a full fledged terminal emulator right in Vim.